# How to use hw-app-solana's signOfflineMessage to sign a message using Ledger?

Tags: ledger

I found that Ledger now supports `signOfflineMessage` for message signing. I have been trying to sign a message which is on the phantom [sandbox](https://r3byv.csb.app/). The method requires a buffer to be signed, so I am trying the following.

```
 const decoded = bs58.decode("RHCXEL9pq4DkYbcjcEk4QdyhYGr6pbZu8aH2ZLXsjyfpi5q8Zn9QLr7BTbaKpx4cVYGutJUUB7W9xMSeWYmba7tG5kSMjSdasxeAR")
 const buffer = Buffer.from(decoded)
 return (await solana.signOffchainMessage(path, message)).signature
```

But the following error is thrown while attempting to sign

```
{
    "name": "TransportStatusError",
    "message": "Ledger device: UNKNOWN_ERROR (0x6a81)",
    "statusCode": 27265,
    "statusText": "UNKNOWN_ERROR"
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!